# Django ModelForm - Create instance with foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm wondering what the correct way to create a model instance with a django model form is when it contains a required FK?  I think it may have to do with the `exclude` class property, but in the view I am trying override this before save.

Model:

```
 class Profile(models.Model):
    client = models.OneToOneField('auth.User')
    first_name = models.TextField(blank=True,)
...
```

Form:

```
class ProfileForm(floppyforms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        exclude = ('client',)
        model = Profile

        widgets = {
            'first_name': floppyforms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name'}),
...
```

View:

```
def post(self, request):
    form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=False)
        form.client = User.objects.create(username=request.POST['email'],)
        form.save()
        return redirect('/success')
    return redirect('/error')
```

The error:

```
django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Profile has no client.
```

Looking at the Admin, I can see that the user has been created however.
[image]

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an error in your views.py. It should be:

```
def post(self, request):
    form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_profile = form.save(commit=False)
        new_profile.client = User.objects.create(username=request.POST['email'],)
        new_profile.save()
        return redirect('/success')
    return redirect('/error')
```

You shouldn't assign the client to your form, but to the in-memory instance `new_profile`, then call `new_profile.save()` to save the `new_profile` to the database.

Comment: Doh.  Thanks for this.